# Change figure as I keep adding text in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

In Beamer, I would like to post a figure, then add some text using `\itemize`, and change the figure inbetween items **without** moving the already posted text.  Here is roughly what I want:

All on the same slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test1}
\pause
\begin{itemize}
\item
Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1 Text 1
\pause
%%Change the original figure to "test2" without moving any already written text.
\pause
\item
Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2 Text 2
\pause
%%Change figure again to "test3" again without moving any text.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And a tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @Christian Thanks, I did not know how to make the code box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, you meant something like this -- if the image should be 'overlayed' (ideally with an other image of same dimensions), it is appropiate to use the `\only<firstframe-endframe>` command, e.g. `\only<1-2>....` showing only on frame 1 to 2.

Use the same command for text lines too, but be aware about the textheight of them!

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%
\only<1-2>{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{image1}%
}%
\only<3-4>{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{image2}%
}%
\only<5-5>{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{image3}%
}%
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-5>And now I show you the \textcolor{brown}{1st} image%
\item<3-5>And now I show you the \textcolor{blue}{2nd} image%
\item<5-5>And now I show you the \textcolor{red}{3rd} image%
\end{itemize}
%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Note** Remove the `demo` option from `\documentclass` specification.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that the new text replaces the old text.  What I would like is a solution that keeps the earlier text, and especially without moving the old text either.

Comment: @Trevor: Ok, that is much easier! I will update

Comment: @Trevor: The synchronizing between text and images depends on your choice, so I can only guess whether you want to show picture, wait, show text etc?

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not really understand until now what the \only command was doing.

Comment: @Trevor: Synchronizing can in most cases be done with `\only`, sometimes in conjunction with `\onslide`, but both methods require careful usage. (and a lot of recompilations ;-))